# Do you have to use the whole ticket

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I have a round trip ticket from Mexico to London, this flight has a connection in Paris, we are currently in Paris.  Do we need to go back to London or would we be able to board in Paris and just not use the first flight.

Comment: Yes, you need to go to London. [Previous questions on related issues](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=leg+return)

Answer (score 0):

If you contact the airline and change your booking, then yes you could board the flight in Paris.  But this would likely involve a change fee and perhaps additional airfare.

If you skip the first flight without changing your booking, then your Paris to Mexico flight will be automatically canceled.